# How to pass multiple values into hive hql for the same hivevar

Tags: hive, hiveql

Requirement :
My Hql has below script in which I want to pass values into the where clause dynamically. How do I dynamically pass using hivevar in below specific scenario where multiple values are expected. Or how do I invoke the hql with hivevar defined for (‘a’,’c’)

Create table newtbl
As select * from temptbl where
id IN (‘a’, ‘c’)